# Neither Nor subject agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

You know that forks don't fly off to the Moon and that neither **apples** nor **anything thing** else on earth **cause** the Sun to crash down on us.

As far as i know , with 'nether-nor', verb **cause** should agree to **anything else**, the closest noun from verb. Then how come the verb is not singular in the sentence above?

Comment: Where is this sentence from? You are right in that the verb **cause** should agree with the subject **anything else** and become **causes**.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is wrong.
You can find the commas in the original sentence.

"You know that forks don't fly off to the Moon and that neither apples, nor anything thing else on earth, cause the Sun to crash down on us."

Answer (score -1):

I found this on [Towson's website](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulesvagr.htm):

> If the individual parts of the compound subject are joined by or or nor, use the verb form (singular or plural) which will agree with the subject closer to the verb.
>
> The ranger or the campers see the bear.
>
> The rangers or the camper sees the bear.

Following this, your sentence would have "cause" agree with "anything else", so it should be "causes".

Comment: Consider a construction such as *I don't think your friends or your wife **like** me*. Where it's *I don't think your wife **likes** me* if we don't have a "compound subject", but native speakers certainly wouldn't adopt your stated principle of "verb agrees with the nearest element of a compound subject" in that context. Personally, I think both versions are at least "acceptable" for OP's *specific* context, but doubtless there will be pedants arguing for/against one or the other.

Comment: I agree that I'd personally use either in a conversation, but I don't think "because I think it sounds decent" would be a good reason to provide a language learner.

Comment: It seems to depend on the *exact* context. But unless you're going to claim that *I don't think your friends or your wife **likes** me* is actually "correct" (and to me that one isn't even *acceptable*), surely we must accept that the "rule" you've cited is even less helpful for learners, since it will lead them to say things that native speakers never would. Maybe there's a better rule, I dunno.

Comment: Purdue also agrees with the rule:  https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html .  Mayhaps you just found the one example that sounds bad, but is technically correct?  :/

Comment: I'm more on board with the "descriptive linguistics" approach than "prescriptive grammar", so from my point of view *sounds bad (and thus **avoided by native speakers**) , but is technically correct* is something of an oxymoron. The "rules" simply codify the forms people actually use, and if there's any conflict I'd normally side with the people (language is "democracy in action", imho! :)

Comment: Whatever - I don't know the full answer to this one, but I've upvoted the *question* in hopes that someone else here can flesh things out a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the sentence is wrong  according to purists but  there are different  versions.

I have  found  a rule  which  says:

If  neither and  nor  are  followed by   singular nouns the  verb  should  be singular but if  neither or nor  is  followed  by  a plural  noun   the  verb be  should  be  plural.
So  the sentence is  right.

I herewith  attach the link to  make  things  clear.

https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-either-or-neither-nor.php

> **Neither apples nor anything else on earth cause  the sun**---------- is
>   correct

Comment: I  would  like  to  know  the  correct  answer  to  this  question.No  answer  or  comment  seems  to  be  correct